# Repair failed due to data corruption in one of the production table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

**Issue description:**

We found data corruption in one of the tables, while performing cluster syncing.

**Corrective actions:**

We have performed `nodetool repair` to sync up the nodes, post removing the corrupted table. There were two, out of four nodes, in the cluster was down before we triggered the `repair`. However, during the repair, all the servers were live and active.

We are using **Cassandra 3.11.1**

Appreciate your help to pinpoint the issue, and let me know reasons to data corruption in table and how we can prevent it?.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: As data in table is corrupted so we would like to know why this happens,what are the reasons to data corruption like this.  so that we can take preventive measures hereafter.

Comment: anyone please ans the question